# PowerMockito - testing methods invoked by constructor

Tags: unit-testing, constructor, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write tests for legacy code. One of the classes I am trying to test is a **constructor**. This constructor itself invokes several other methods.

I am trying to write a unit test for this constructor to verify that the methods invoked by the constructor are indeed invoked.

I am using PowerMock 1.5.5 and Mockito 1.9.5 with Test NG with eclipse (org.testng.eclipse - 6.8.6.20141201_2240) on eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0).

Could I please ask for guidance on what I am doing wrong? 
I get the exception:

> Wanted but not invoked: classWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS();
>   -> at com.example.constructortester.MakerOfClassWithConstructorTest.testSomething(MakerOfClassWithConstructorTest.java:30)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

I expected that doSomethingWithS should have been invoked, but the error message I get tells me that the Mock itself is not used, and therefore the method I expected to be invoked on the spy can never be invoked.

Below are the code snippets:

**The legacy class that has the constructor, which in turns calls another method**

```
package com.example.constructortester;

public class ClassWithConstructor {

    public static final String MODIFIED = "Modified:";

    public ClassWithConstructor(String s) {
        String returnVal = doSomethingWithS(s);
        System.out.println("ClassWithConstructor::ClassWithConstructor - :"
                + returnVal);
    }

    protected String doSomethingWithS(String s) {
        System.out
                .println("ClassWithConstructor::doSomethingWithS - Something with s:"
                        + s);
        return MODIFIED + s;
    }
}
```

**My class that I use as a builder:**

```
package com.example.constructortester;

public class MakerOfClassWithConstructor {

    public MakerOfClassWithConstructor() {
    }

    public void doSomething(String s) {
        new ClassWithConstructor(s);
    }
}
```

**Finally, the TestNG test**:

```
package com.example.constructortester;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@PrepareForTest(MakerOfClassWithConstructor.class)
public class MakerOfClassWithConstructorTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        final String someString = "Test";
        final String someOtherString = "SomeOtherTest";

        ClassWithConstructor spyClassWithConstructor = spy(new ClassWithConstructor(
                someString));
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassWithConstructor.class)
                .withArguments(someString).thenReturn(spyClassWithConstructor);

        PowerMockito.doReturn(someOtherString).when(spyClassWithConstructor)
                .doSomethingWithS(someString);
        // PowerMockito.when(spyClassWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS(someString))
        // .thenReturn(someOtherString);

        new MakerOfClassWithConstructor().doSomething(someString);

        // This works
        PowerMockito.verifyNew(ClassWithConstructor.class).withArguments(
                someString);

        // This fails with error:
        // Wanted but not invoked:
        // classWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS(<any>);
        // -> at
        // com.example.constructortester.MakerOfClassWithConstructorTest.testSomething(MakerOfClassWithConstructorTest.java:30)
        // Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
        Mockito.verify(spyClassWithConstructor, times(1)).doSomethingWithS(
                someOtherString);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact exception that you are getting?

Comment: Hi: I get the exception:         
        Wanted but not invoked:
        classWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS(<any>);
        -> at
        com.example.constructortester.MakerOfClassWithConstructorTest.testSomething(MakerOfClassWithConstructorTest.java:30)
        Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Java bug.

Try to add `-noverify` in the VM arguments of the test launcher.
Or (the best solution) update the JDK. Mine was 1.7.0_u67 and I updated it to version 1.7.0_u79 and worked (even without the `-noverify`).

Comment: After adding this argument, android studio is not coming up. Could you please let me that how can I remove without start android studio?

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration. Try to remove the argument from the 'studio64.exe.vmoptions' or 'idea.properties' file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the method using the mock object before verifying it
so you should add a line

```
spyClassWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS(someOtherString);
```

before

```
 Mockito.verify(spyClassWithConstructor, times(1)).doSomethingWithS(
            someOtherString);
```

In your case it is not going to verify(skipping it) because you have not even called the method, Verification can be done only after you call the method

Comment: Hi Vikas: Thank you for helping me. My code is indirectly calling the  `ClassWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS(someOtherString)` as part of the `new MakerOfClassWithConstructor().doSomething(someString);`

Comment: Since you are verifying a method via spyClassWithConstructor it requires to be called from that object only i.e if you want to verify a method call on  something on spyClassWithConstructor then you should have a spyClassWithConstructor.* call

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My problem in this case is that the method that I want invoked `ClassWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS(someOtherString)` is actually invoked by the `ClassWithConstructor`constructor. This being legacy code, I am unable to change the `ClassWithConstructor` class or invoke the `ClassWithConstructor.doSomethingWithS(someOtherString)` directly.